# WPF Popup close automatically

Tags: wpf, popup, move

How to close the `WPF Popup` in a WPF Control if clicked **outside the Popup area** or if the **Parent Control is moved** ?

I cannot check it from the Parent Control, Everything must be done by the control itself.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
 <Popup x:Name="pop" IsOpen="False"  StaysOpen="False">
```

Comment: Yes this really works, the only problem is that if you move your mouse outside the Popup and scroll.. it stays open :-/

Comment: "When the StaysOpen property is set to true, Popup stays open until it is explicitly closed by setting the IsOpen property to false. When StaysOpen is false, the Popup control intercepts all mouse and keyboard events to determine when one of these events occurs outside the Popup control." that is what I found on MSDN.

Comment: Perhaps not. I'm trying to make a popup keyboard that disappears when you touch outside the box. With StaysOpen set to false, it never opens in the first place.

Comment: StaysOpen appears not to work with touch events on Win7, but does appear to work on Win8.

Answer (score 2):

in WinRT and universal app you can use

> IsLightDismissEnabled="True"

its will close automatically when click any where.